# jquery terminal to connect to remote host

Tags: angularjs, jquery-terminal

I am new to `Jquery` terminal. Can i use this to connect to remote `unix/linux` host though web browser? I don't find examples on this do you have any examples?  I am also interested even if there something in angular.

Comment: If you just want access to the shell you can use https://github.com/jcubic/leash that use jQuery Terminal

Comment: Users may use all unix commands enabled for their roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i use this to connect to remote unix/linux host though web
>   browser?

**NO.**

> JQuery Terminal Emulator is a plugin for creating command line
>   interpreters in your applications. It can automatically call JSON-RPC
>   service when user type commands or you can provide an object with
>   methods, each method will be invoke on user command. Object can have
>   nested objects which will create nested interpreter. You can also use
>   a function in which you can parse user command by your own. It′s ideal
>   if you want to provide additional functionality for power users. It
>   can also be used as debuging tool.

http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for embedded ssh terminal in a web page.  something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988171/web-based-ssh-terminal-to-connect-to-remote-machines

Comment: You can try https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox or https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firessh/

Comment: for shell in a box i need to install server on particular port number on each of the remote systems that I have.  as per my requirement I can not install anything on the remote machine, i just need console to be opened in the browser tab.  Users may use any kind of browser and may not force them to use plugins.

Comment: https://github.com/JohnTroony/php-webshells - tons of php web-shells. **BE CAREFUL WITH THAT !**